# MYSQL select and group if column value

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL table with - to simplify it - three columns: name, address, and primary residence.

There can be rows with duplicate names. I want to make a select statement that will return a person's name and address. If they are in the table twice, that means they have two addresses. However, if one of them is the "primary residence" i want it to only return the primary residence. Otherwise, it should return both addresses.
Thanks!

Table:

```
Name | Address | Primary Residence
John Smith | 123 Main Str | Yes
John Smith | 456 June Str | 
Mike Dore  | 893 West St  |
Jake John  | 999 East St  |
Jake John  | 145 South St |
```

Returns:

```
Name | Address
John Smith | 123 Main Str
Mike Dore  | 893 West St
Jake John  | 999 East St
Jake John  | 145 South St
```

Comment: We are not a code-writing service. What have you done so far?

Comment: I have done it in PHP but I want to know if it can be done in one line of MYSQL. I can not think of anything; looking for direction.

Comment: Then you need a mentor or a tutor, not a Q&A site.

Comment: You need a mentor or a tutor!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way...

```
CREATE TABLE addresses 
(Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,Address VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,is_primary TINYINT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY (name,address)
);

INSERT INTO addresses VALUES
('John Smith','123 Main Str',1),
('John Smith','456 June Str',NULL),
('Mike Dore','893 West St',NULL),
('Jake John','999 East St',NULL),
('Jake John','145 South St',NULL);


SELECT * FROM addresses;
+------------+--------------+------------+
| Name       | Address      | is_primary |
+------------+--------------+------------+
| Jake John  | 145 South St |       NULL |
| Jake John  | 999 East St  |       NULL |
| John Smith | 123 Main Str |          1 |
| John Smith | 456 June Str |       NULL |
| Mike Dore  | 893 West St  |       NULL |
+------------+--------------+------------+

SELECT DISTINCT x.name
              , COALESCE(y.address,x.address) address
           FROM addresses x 
           LEFT 
           JOIN addresses y 
             ON y.name = x.name 
            AND y.is_primary = 1;
+------------+--------------+
| name       | address      |
+------------+--------------+
| Jake John  | 145 South St |
| Jake John  | 999 East St  |
| John Smith | 123 Main Str |
| Mike Dore  | 893 West St  |
+------------+--------------+
```

Comment: +1, given the question description, yours is the correct answer, not the one accepted. Too bad.

Comment: +1 for helpful tips how it could be done

Answer (score 2):

it could be done with Sub Query.

```
select * from TBL where NAME not in (select NAME from TBL where residence='PRI')
union 
select * from TBL where residence='PRI';
```

EDIT:
AFTER QUESTION UPDATE :

```
select * from TBL where NAME not in (select NAME from TBL where residence='yes')
union 
select * from TBL where residence='yes'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39493/5/0

Comment: I'm just starting playing DBA. When I saw Strawberry's reply i thought "He knows how to play!".